# Unable to connect to Oracle on Azure Data Factory

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, azure-data-factory, connector

I'm trying to connect to my on-premise Oracle database in order to migrate and copy some tables over to Azure SQL, but am not able to do so despite making sure all the connection parameters match the provided values in tnsnames.

Am I missing something? The error says the socket is closed but haven't gotten any useful information other than [this prior issue, but doesn't contain any solution.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28b6de2b-592b-4a39-b4fe-de0551f563da/socket-closed-error-when-connecting-on-prem-oracle-to-data-factory) I currently use Oracle 11.2.0.3 so the ADF connector should support this version.

Not sure what else I need to check. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenprint shows you are using the *AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime* but as you say your Oracle db is on-premises you would need a Self-hosted Integration runtime (SHIR) as per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle#prerequisites).  You would still need an SHIR for an IaaS Oracle db.  Ideally the SHIR should be 'close' to the datasource so probably on-premises in the same network.

Comment: Interesting I missed that part. Will take a look into it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxy or firewall configured?
Have you tried creating the linked service and then testing the connection? Sometimes it occurred to me that I failed to test the connection of a new linked service but when creating it and retesting the connection is successful ...